# A simple sql query question

Tags: sql

suppose I have a table like this:

table1:

```
name     favorite_music
 a         country
 b         rock
 a         jazz
 b         jazz
```

How can I do this query: find the names whose favorite_music style has *both* "country" *and* "jazz". For the example above, it should be only "a".

Comment: With `SELECT DISTINCT name FROM table1 WHERE`... `favorite_music = 'country' AND favorite_music = 'jazz'` will return no rows. `favorite_music = 'country' OR favorite_music = 'jazz'` will result in both `a` and `b` being returned. From what the OP is asking, only `a` should be returned because only `a` likes both country and jazz.

Comment: Yep, you cannot do this with a simple `OR` expression. It requires a join or nested query, so that there are effectively two passes over the table, one for each `favorite_music` value desired.

Comment: +1 Good question, although I wouldn't think of it as a "simple" query.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should get them:

```
select name
from table1
where favorite_music = 'country'
intersect
select name
from table1
where favorite_music = 'jazz'
```

**EDIT**: The question is not very clear. The query above will return every name thas has both jazz and country as favorite music styles (in your example table, name='a')

**EDIT 2**: Just for fun, one example that should do it with one single scan, using a subquery:

```
select name from (
    select 
    name, 
    count(case when favorite_music = 'country' then 1 end) as likes_country,
    count(case when favorite_music = 'jazz' then 1 end) as likes_jazz,
    from table1
    where favorite_music in ('country', 'jazz')
    group by name
) where likes_country > 0 and likes_jazz > 0
```

Comment: +1 Unlike the other queries, this one will only return names for which there is a row where `favorite_music` is `country` and a row where `favorite_music` is `jazz`.

Comment: @cHao How would you do an equivalent query with an `OR`?

Comment: rereading it, you wouldn't.  That's why i quickly retracted my comment and downvote.  :)

Comment: @baboonWorksFine `INTERSECT` might not be exactly efficient, but it is the right concept for my interpretation of this query. I have added an alternative that it is less clear but will be probably faster if you do not have an index on favorite_music.

Answer (score 8):

```
SELECT t1.name  
FROM table1 as t1  
INNER JOIN table1 AS t2 ON t1.name = t2.name 
WHERE t1.favorite_music = 'jazz' AND t2.favorite_music = 'country'
```

Comment: This is pretty close.  There should probably be join conditions though.

Comment: @chao - wow can't believe i left that line out.  The "There are 3 new answers" distracted me...fixed in edit.

Answer (score 1):

This will return all names that have *at least* country and jazz as favorite music:

```
select name from table1 where
  favorite_music in ('country', 'jazz')
group by name having count(name) = 2
```

This will return all names that have *exactly* (not more) country and jazz as favorite music:

```
select name from table1 t1 where
not exists (
  select * from table1 t2 where
    t1.name = t2.name and
    t2.favorite_music not in ('country', 'jazz')
)
group by name having count(name) = 2
```

The double negative can be tricky. You can read it like this: select all people who *don't* like music that *isn't* country or jazz. That means that they *only* like music that's country or jazz. The `group by` and `having count = 2` just takes care that what they like is country *and* jazz.

Answer (score 0):

Try this-->

```
select x.name from table1 x, table1 y
where
x.name = y.name and
x.favorite_music = 'country' and 
y.favorite_music = 'jazz'
```

Answer (score 0):

### pl/sql query

select name
from table1
where favorite_music='country' 
or 
favorite_music= 'jazz'
group by name 
having COUNT(name) > 1

OR

select name from 
(select name,favorite_music from table1
where favorite_music ='country' 
or 
favorite_music = 'jazz'
group by name,favorite_music)
group by name
 having COUNT(*) > 1